Bind and validations basic questions

How can we use a gender field and apply validation on client side and server side in Blazor?
Can we use multiple events from one control using @bind?
Can we have relative path other than root in HTML and JS injection? If not why?


For your question one :

How can we use a gender field and apply validation on client side and
server side in Blazor?

Here's how you can achieve the above:
Create a class which handles you form model:
public class MyFormModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is required.")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

And in your HTML handle validation error like below :
<EditForm Model="@myFormModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
    <input type="text" id="gender" @bind="myFormModel.Gender" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => myFormModel.Gender)" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

Validate same accordingly in server side like below:
public class MyComponent : ComponentBase
{
    private MyFormModel myFormModel = new MyFormModel();

    protected async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(myFormModel);
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(myFormModel, validationContext, validationResults, true))
        {
           
            foreach (var error in validationResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage); // all error for server side validation 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // No validation errors - successful happy path here
        }
    }
}

For your second question two:

Can we use multiple events from one control using @bind?

The short and straightforward answer is Yes, you can do so. You need to handle the events explicitly.
<input @bind="value" @oninput="HandleInput" @onchange="HandleChange" />

In the above code sample HandleInput is called on each key up-down event by the user and HandleChange will be called when the input field loses its focus.
For your question three:

Can we have relative path other than root in HTML and JS injection? If
not why?

Yes you can use relative path other than the root HTML and Javascript Injector in blazor. You need to correctly refer those from the wwwroot directory for static files.
if in case of a static file in wwwroot:
<!-- Inside an HTML file in wwwroot -->
<script src="js/myScript.js"></script>

if in case of a subdirectory inside wwwroot:
<!-- Inside wwwroot/subdirectory/index.html -->
<script src="../js/myScript.js"></script>

